# Controlled Impedance Microstrip Frequency

Tags: characteristic-impedance, microstrip, controlled-impedance

Are you supposed to calculate the characteristic impedance for the frequency you are using or at 1GHz? I see pretty much everything calculated at 1GHz in all examples and papers.

For example - for GPS - you're supposed to have a 50 ohm characteristic impedance... is that 50 ohms at 1575 MHz (GPS freq) or at 1 GHz? The same goes for GSM - which can be at either 850, 900, 1800, or 1900 MHz - it always requires a 50 ohm characteristic impedance for the microstrip trace from the transceiver pad to the antenna connector.

Thoughts?

Comment: For typical microstrip geometries, it's no too common to have a very strong frequency dependency. Can you give an example where the computed Z0 depends strongly on frequency? What geometry and what frequency range were you looking at?

Answer (score 2):

Dielectric constant for most PCB materials fall with increasing frequency. This is a logarithmic curve, so in practice it's fairly flat from 1-2GHz and up. That is the reason I would calculate characteristic impedance at 1-2GHz and be happy with that even at much higher frequencies.

Notice that you may easily have +/-10% production tolerance on characteristic impedance in inner layers (for narrow traces) and maybe +/-20% on outer layers. So don't overdo this.

Sorry for the late answer - hope it's still useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you design it for the precise frequency you are using.

Practically, the slight variation won't be worth the extra "balancing" effort during design and one reason many designs are done at 1GHz is because the board material is characterized at 1GHz. So, the loss tangent and dielectric constant are many times only given to you at 1GHz (some are given at 100MHz and 10GHz as well) but the 1GHz value is, more often than not, good enough.

Comment: So you're saying that I can safely design a 50 ohm microstrip at 1GHz for use with 2.4GHz RF?

Comment: Assuming that you're using FR-4, there's most likely a bigger variation from board to board than there is in any given board over that frequency span.....so, the answer to your question is yes. Now, part of the word "safely" implies that you're allowing for manufacturing and material tolerances as long as for the possibility that you'll need to tune your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic impedance of a transmission line (above 1 MHz typically) is determined by the series inductance per metre and parallel capacitance per metre like below: -

\$Z_0 =\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$

The inductance is largely determined by dimensions and these are constant. If you know the permittivity of the material and how it changes from one frequency to another, you can predict how the capacitance changes with frequency and predict the new value for \$Z_0\$ based on the baseline value at another frequency.

Comment: I'm aware of this equation and thus z0 shouldn't depend on frequency... but in all calculators I've seen, including AWR Microwave Office, when you change the frequency of the RF and nothing else the impedance changes hugely. Andy - how to do you do this when designing a microstrip trace?

Comment: Have you tried this one - http://www1.sphere.ne.jp/i-lab/ilab/tool/ms_line_e.htm - I put in some values and got hardly any change between 1MHz and 10GHz but it does depend on the permittivity of FR4 and this changes with frequency and can make results more pronounced.

Comment: Ditto this one: http://www.emtalk.com/mscalc.php?er=4&h=1&h_units_list=hmm&f=0.001&Zo=74.145014311&EL=204.916475958&Operation=Analyze&Wa=1&W_units_list=Wmm&La=10&L_units_list=Lmm